# Get the value of the property of the object whose name begins with a number

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I'm fetching data from website that returns me an object in a **string** like this:

```
{
    index: 1,
    commentNumber: 20,
    feedComments: {
        3465665: {
            text: "I do not agree",
            likeRatio: 0
        },
        6169801: {
            text: "Hello",
            likeRatio: 12
        },
        7206201: {
            text: "Great job!",
            likeRatio: 5
        }
    }
}
```

I want to work with this as an object, that's pretty easy to do, I'll just do this:

```
string objectString = GetData(); // Artificial GetData() method
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(objectString);
```

And now I can easily get all properties I want from this object using **dynamic**

The problem is pretty obvious now, I want to get properties, whose name starts with number (the object data structure I fetch is just designed that way). But property/field names you get from object cannot begin with a number.

```
int commentNumber = data.commentNumber; // Works fine

string commentText = data.feedComments.3465665.text; // Obviously won't compile
```

Is there any way to do this?

Note that I want to work with data I fetch as it was an object, I know I get get the comment text right from the string that **GetData()** method returns using some regex or something, but that's something I want to avoid.

Comment: Why not parse this into proper C# objects? It makes everything so much easier to deal with.

Comment: Also this number property you speak of is basically just a dictionary key of int

Comment: Also know, every time you use the type `dynamic`, you are usually solving a problem by creating 2 or more other problems

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really be parsing the JSON into concrete C# classes. Dynamic is slow and vulnerable to runtime errors that are hard to detect.
The comments will go into a Dictionary. For example:

```
public class Root
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int CommentNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<long, FeedComment> FeedComments { get; set; }
}

public class FeedComment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int LikeRatio { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(objectString);
```

Now you can access the comments very easily:

```
var commentText = result.FeedComments[3465665].Text
```